# connecting lv maxsonar ez arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors

I am not 100% sure this question relevant here , but question is I have lv maxsonar ez which need 5v. I am powering my uno with  9v battery. And I have few other sensors also connected to 3.3v. But I have neopixel 3 meter LED which is powering with external power source which is 5v 4 amp. So My question is shall I connect my sonar sensor to the external power or keep with my uno 5v power ?

Thanks

Comment: Don't [cross post on other SE sites](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40752799/connecting-lv-maxsonar-ez-arduino).

Comment: Sure, I got confused because I was afraid that this question won't be relevant here. But I got the answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the question is still relevant.
You should keep the maxsonar powered from Uno power if you don't want to burn it. Even if you use 9v Battery, Arduino Uno have internal 5v regulator. So it would be safer to supply the sensor from Arduino 5V (**not Vin**) pin.

Comment: To be precise, the pin labelled **5V**.